# Using %rowtype when returning in a PostgreSQL function

Tags: database, postgresql, function, plpgsql, return-type

If I have a function that returns only one row with some columns from a table. Do I need to add `%rowtype` in the function return declaration?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(int n)
RETURNS tableName%rowtype AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    r tableName%rowtype;    
BEGIN   
    select a,b,c into r from tableName where d=n;
    return r;
$BODY$
END;
```

Comment: This looks wrong - `tableName%rowtype` should have ALL the columns in `tableName`, not just those you're selecting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### About `%ROWTYPE`

The `%ROWTYPE` construct is only good for portability to other RDBMS. Rarely useful, since PL/pgSQL functions are hardly portable to begin with.
*If* you are going to use it, it's only meant for **variable declaration** inside PL/pgSQL function, not to declare the `RETURN` type, which is part of the outer SQL syntax.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES)

> (Since every table has an associated composite type of the same name,
> it actually does not matter in PostgreSQL whether you write `%ROWTYPE`
> or not. But the form with `%ROWTYPE` is more portable.)

#### Answer

This would achieve what you seem to be trying:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_plpgsql(_n int)
  RETURNS tbl
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN   
  RETURN (SELECT t FROM tbl t where tbl_id = _n);  -- selecting whole row
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test_plpgsql(1);
```

But if it's as simple as that, use a simpler SQL function to begin with:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_sql(_n int)
  RETURNS SETOF tbl
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl_id = _n;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test_sql(1);
```

Your original code example had too many issues. Search for more [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql) examples to get a grasp on basic syntax.

Comment: Extremely useful, especially with `language sql`. Now I can simply modularize all sorts of complex sql queries