# RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set

Tags: postgresql

I have written a function which takes parameter called id that gets integer. When function is called, it returns specific user's info that is user_id, name and password.

If specific user does not exist, function returns the last user of the table.

The function is:

```
create function getUser(id int) 
returns table(user_id int, name varchar, password varchar)
language plpgsql as 
$$
declare
   info users%rowtype;
begin
   select
      *
   from
     users
 into 
     info
 where 
     user_id = id;
 
 if not found then
     raise warning 'such user does not exist';
     select
         * 
     from 
         users
     into
         info
     where 
         user_id = MAX(users.user_id);
 end if;
 return info;
 end;
 $$;
```

but the result is:

```
 RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set
 LINE 27:     return info;
                ^
 HINT:  Use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY.
```

users table consists of such columns and rows:

```
user_id | name   | password |
```

I don't know where i made mistake. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: You want `return query`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using %rowtype when returning in a PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297404/using-rowtype-when-returning-in-a-postgresql-function)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have used return query but still i faced error

Comment: @Kendle no, error is not in %rowtype

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html

- **3.6.1.1. RETURN**

> RETURN with an expression terminates the function and returns the
> value of expression to the caller. This form is used for PL/pgSQL
> functions **that do not return a set**.

- **43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY**

> When a PL/pgSQL function is declared to **return SETOF sometype**, the
> procedure to follow is slightly different. In that case, the
> individual items to return are specified by a sequence of RETURN NEXT
> or RETURN QUERY commands, and then a final RETURN command with no
> argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing.
> RETURN NEXT can be used with both scalar and composite data types;
> with a composite result type, an entire “table” of results will be
> returned. RETURN QUERY appends the results of executing a query to the
> function's result set

your code:  `select * from users into info where user_id = id;` can return more than 1 rows, So you should use **return query**

another issue is your declare variable user_id the same as identifier user_id, the parser don't know how to deal with it.
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a28ae0db4f8c074ada764353be21619c)

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a variable of data type `users` and do something like this:

```
create function getUser(id int) 
   returns  users
language plpgsql as 
$$
declare
  info users;
begin  
 select * from users where users.user_id=id into info;
 if info is null then
     select * from users order by user_id desc limit 1 into info;
 end if;
return info;
end;
$$;
```

Demo in [sqldaddy](https://sqldaddy.io/b06b0977)